# Bootstrap toggler won't collapse once clicked on

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I'm getting familiar with MDbootstrap and bootstrap 4. I recently created a website using the toggle with no problem however, with this website I'm creating, the toggle won't close once clicked on. I can't seem to figure it out. I have a feeling this is a MDbootstrap error as the I have seen others comment about this but no answer. As I'm learning more about MDBootstrap, I'm running into a lot of errors. Can anyone help me?

HTML

```
<!--Navbar /Logo-->   
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" style="background-color:#7e57c2;">

 <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="color:#FFF;">Ride with Amy</a>

 <!--Toggle Button--> 
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
 aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:#FFF;"></span></button>


 <!--Navbar links-->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"
        href="#about_link"  style="color:#FFF;">About</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"
        href="#schedule_link" style="color:#FFF;">Schedule</a>
    </li>

    <!--Social Media Icons-->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/ridewithamy/" title="Follow on Instagram" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#FFF;"></i></a></li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/amy.kaczmarek.3" title="Follow on Linkedin" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#FFF;"></i></a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your html code work fine when i check , no problem at all. You please check your bootstrap dependencies** ..